# Python for looping to while looping

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I need some help with converting the below code into something a bit more manageable.
I'm pretty sure I need modify it to include some while statements. But have been hitting my head against a wall for the last day or so. I think I'm close....

```
for LevelItemList[1] in LevelUrlList[1]:
if LevelItemList[1][1] == "Folder":
    printFolderHeader(1,LevelItemList[1][0])
    LevelUrlList[2] = parseHTML (LevelItemList[1][2])

    for LevelItemList[2] in LevelUrlList[2]:
        if LevelItemList[2][1] == "Folder":
            printFolderHeader(2,LevelItemList[2][0])
            LevelUrlList[3] = parseHTML (LevelItemList[2][2])

            for LevelItemList[3] in LevelUrlList[3]:
                if LevelItemList[3][1] == "Folder":
                    printFolderHeader(3,LevelItemList[3][0])
                    LevelUrlList[4] = parseHTML (LevelItemList[3][2])

                    for LevelItemList[4] in LevelUrlList[4]:
                        if LevelItemList[4][1] == "Folder":
                            printFolderHeader(4,LevelItemList[4][0])
                            LevelUrlList[5] = parseHTML (LevelItemList[4][2])

                            for LevelItemList[5] in LevelUrlList[5]:
                                if LevelItemList[5][1] == "Folder":
                                    printFolderHeader(5,LevelItemList[5][0])
                                    LevelUrlList[6] = parseHTML (LevelItemList[5][2])

                                    for LevelItemList[6] in LevelUrlList[6]:
                                        printPage(6,LevelItemList[6][0])

                                    printFolderFooter(5,LevelItemList[5][0])

                                else:
                                    printPage(5,LevelItemList[5][0])
                            printFolderFooter(4,LevelItemList[4][0])                                
                        else:   
                            printPage(4,LevelItemList[4][0])
                    printFolderFooter(3,LevelItemList[3][0])

                else:
                    printPage(3,LevelItemList[3][0])
            printFolderFooter(2,LevelItemList[2][0])

        else:
            printPage(2,LevelItemList[2][0])
    printFolderFooter(1,LevelItemList[1][0])

else:
    printPage(1,LevelItemList[1][0])
```

Comment: Or recursion...looks like you're traversing a directory tree.

Comment: Recursion looks like the way to go to me.

Comment: If this code works, it might be a better fit for `codereview.stackexchange`, but I guess we'll wait and see if others agree ...

Comment: What makes you think that converting `for` statements to `while` statements will help anything? If we knew that, that might give us a clue as to what to look at.

Comment: The above code does work. Didn't know about codereview.stackexchange. At the moment there is a lot of code duplication for each "level". As more conditions are adding the duplication with get bigger and bigger. Thus trying to simplify it so the If case is only started once and just iterates X number of times.

Comment: In your for loop, why are you assigning the LevelUrlList to a list item in LevelItemList? I think more context is needed to make sense of this question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full context of the code, but I think you can reduce it down to something like this:

```
def printTheList(LevelItemList, index):
    for item in LevelItemList:
        if item[1] == "Folder":
            printFolderHeader(index,item[0])
            printTheList(parseHTML (item[2]), index + 1) # note the + 1
            printFolderFooter(index,item[0])
        else:
            printPage(index,item[0])

# and the initial call looks like this.
printTheList(LevelUrlList[1], 1)
```

This code makes the assumption that you don't actually need to assign the values into LevelUrlList and LevelItemList the way you are doing in your code. If you do need that data later, I suggest passing in a different data structure to hold the resulting values.